# cohomology of a symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{F}_3$ be the sign representation of $S_3.$ What is $H^i (S_3, \mathbb{F}_3)?$ I think it is $\mathbb{F}_3$ in all degrees but I am not sure in my calculations. Namely, I used Serre-Leray spectral sequence and reduced it to $H^i (\mathbb{Z}/3, \mathbb{F}/3)^{\mathbb{Z}/2}$ where the action is trivial and it seems to me that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ doesn't act on these cohomology groups. Any references are appreciated.

Comment: See also Lemma $6.3$ in the book [cohomology of finite groups](https://books.google.at/books?id=H7TxCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=cohomology+groups+H%5Ei(S3,F3)&source=bl&ots=VC1fYhGehV&sig=ACfU3U3iWp2Nf3DG3yjFjWTm2E4ZNqkTvw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFk6fT8bj2AhWehP0HHbltDfQQ6AF6BAgYEAM#v=onepage&q=cohomology%20groups%20H%5Ei(S3%2CF3)&f=false).

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is a calculation for the trivial module.

Comment: The first line of the proof of Lemma 6.3 states a computation of $H^*(S_3; \mathbb{F}_3)$.

Comment: I agree with the reduction but disagree that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is acting trivially on $H^i(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{F}_3)$. Shouldn't it be $S_3 / A_3$ acting by $-1$ on $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Comment: @hunter Yes, it acts by -1 on F_3. But note that Z/2 also acts on Z/3 since S_3 is the semidirect product. Also, H^*(Z/3, F_3)=k[X, Y]/X^2 where deg(X)=1, deg(Y)=2 and H^1(Z/3, F_3)=Hom_{twisted}(Z/3, F_3). So, since Z/2 acts nontrivially both on Z/3 and F_3, it acts trivially on Hom_{twisted}(Z/3, F_3) => acts trivially on X => acts trivially on Y since Y is the image of X under the Bockstein homomorphism => acts trivially on all cohomology groups since H^*(Z/3, F_3) is generated by X, Y.